# Each other’s nose or each other’s noses?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, possessives, reflexives

Should it be singular or plural after “each other’s” here.

> 1. They touched each other’s **nose**.
> 2. They touched each other’s **noses**.

Are both correct?

John Lawler notes [in another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274597/does-each-other-function-as-singular-or-plural/498306#498306) that *each other* can be broken up. This would give us:

> 3. They each touched the other's **nose**
> 4. *They each touched the other's **noses**

However, this rewriting of the sentences seems to be slightly different, perhaps because of the definite article, *the*, before the word *other's*.

---

**Note:**

Of course, it's trivially true in relation to this question that the example (4) would be fine if  people had several noses. The asterisk in the example indicates that this is not a grammatical means of indicating the same meaning as given in (1).

Comment: ***Work/s*** in your cited context can be either singular *or* plural (compare *He's a great artist! I really like his **work/s***), so it doesn't really tell you much about how "each other's NOUN" works in such contexts. A better example context might be, say, [*They touched each other's **nose/s.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+other%27s+nose%2Ceach+other%27s+noses&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) As you'll see from that chart, most people use the plural there, but singular is far from unknown.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So are both correct in my example?

Comment: Define "correct". As it happens, my natural inclination was to go for the singular in both the ***work*** and the ***nose*** examples. But if there *was* really a concept of "correct usage", it could only apply to ***nose/s*** - because as I pointed out, both ***work*** and ***works*** can often be effectively synonymous. But ***nose*** and ***noses*** are obviously completely different - you couldn't possibly say something like *She's got a great face for a model! I really like her **noses**!*

Comment: I don't think the edit was a particularly good one. The reason for closure was not because you asked about "each other's work" vs "each other's works", so changing *work* with *nose* still doesn't show research or effort. P.S Use the past simple for the original example: “Researchers **cited**…” just like you did for "touched"

Comment: No one tell you whether researchers admired one work or many works of other researchers. Either could make sense. If I admired your autobiography, and you liked mine, then "each other's *work*" works.

Comment: @Mari-LouA When describing writing, the convention is to use the present tense, not the past, though. Especially with academic writing.

Comment: @Araucaria.  I would disagree, the original "**The researchers cite each other’s work(s)**", which is still in the title, sounds odd, as if describing a habitual or obligatory event, maybe where the OP studies it is like that, but without more context, the sentence sounds a little odd. The past tense sounds better to my ears.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's part of what we teach on our academic skills courses at universities in the UK to use the present tense when referring to the content of written texts, including when referring to the authors. So for example we would always write "Smith (2020) argue**s** that xyz" rather than *argued.* Have a look at [this helpful page from Texas State University](https://tinyurl.com/kk85tx9k). PS: might make an interesting or useful Q here or on ELL!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, you'll need to vote to reopen it too!

Comment: There is a comprehensive (near-) overview of the distributive singular and when to use it at ['everybody's using a cell phone' vs 'everybody's using cell phones'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/everybodys-using-a-cell-phone-vs-everybodys-using-cell-phones). Rappaport has 'When each part of a plural subject possesses something individually, the thing possessed is generally used in the plural as well. For example:

The two women blew their noses.' However, for this special case, [Jakub Marian](https://jakubmarian.com/each-others-vs-each-others-in-english/) has ...

Comment: done the research: 'What about the noun that follows “each other’s”—are we supposed to use a singular noun (e.g. “each other’s face”) or a plural noun (e.g. “each other’s faces”)?

The answer is: **Both forms are common**.' // [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=touched+each+other%E2%80%99s+nose%2Ctouched+each+other%E2%80%99s+noses&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)  would be a good place to try to check usage in individual cases; 'touched each other’s noses' seems the more common.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I feel I'm getting sucked into a meaningless disagreement. I already voted to reopen at least once (possibly *twice*, with the Q being closed *again* in between, I don't recall). But if one or more mods still wants it closed I think we're just p***ing in the wind.

Comment: Perhaps it's an age thing. Here's the usage chart for [***do each other's job/s***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+each+other%27s+job%2Cdo+each+other%27s+jobs&year_start=1945&year_end=1965&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) in the post-war decades when I was picking up my language skills. During that period, the singular was most common, but it's all changed now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aha, but I've addressed the so-called 'research' issue to placate the modems and further highlight the rub. And, after all, you did bother to go and do the further edit! So I think you efforts deserve a reopen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Pinging in the wind?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unless, of course, you mean postulating in the wind -  but you need more asterisks there.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: One man's postulate is another man's piss-take! :) But the wise man doesn't postulate taking waste fluids out of the moderators!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Definitely changing: just look at how kids these days construe *none* and *neither* to be plural not singular as we were taught. CRINGE! :)

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think I was ever taught anything like that. We didn't even waste time on stuff like ***who / whom***, and we *certainly* didn't know about not ending sentences with preposition, and that sort of garbage. But we had to get our heads round English from Chaucer thru Shakespeare to Dickens to Hemmingway, which covered a wide range. But it's no surprise to me that most instances of [*They touched] [each **the** other's hand*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22each+the+other%27s+hand%22) are a century or two old. Somehow, we just lost that article, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

*Correct* is somewhat subjective here. One version is more logical; the other is more common. Sometimes you must decide between standing on principle and sounding normal. Says one linguist:

> What about the noun that follows “each other’s”—are we supposed to use
> a singular noun (e.g. “each other’s face”) or a plural noun (e.g.
> “each other’s faces”)?
>
> The answer is: Both forms are common. Since “each other’s” basically
> means “(mutually) the other person’s”, and we wouldn’t say “the other
> person’s faces” (unless the other person is two-faced), it makes more
> sense to say “each other’s face”. Nevertheless, the plural form seems
> to be more common in modern usage, so it can hardly be considered
> incorrect. In summary:
>
> *We saw each other’s faces.* (correct, more common)
> *We saw each other’s face.* (correct, more logical)
>
> <sub>Source: [Jakub Marian — Each other’s vs. each others’ in English](https://jakubmarian.com/each-others-vs-each-others-in-english/)</sub>

In these search results at the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/), you can see it in action and judge for yourself:

[`each other 's face`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=114825064)
[`each other 's faces`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=114825065)
[`each other 's nose`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=114825072)
[`each other 's noses`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=114825074)

Comment: Not only is the plural more common, but it also has a logical basis (apparently missed by Marian): The subject is plural, and it does not appear that multiple people are touching only one nose (or that multiple people are seeing only one face).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan — One nose touched per person in the above sentences.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so plural people touching plural noses. It makes sense.